# How can I load an image into the back buffer?

Tags: c++, directx, directx9

How can I load and display an Image?... 
I have tried something but it didnt.. worked.. this is what I've tried..

File : StrikeOps_main.cpp .. void : render_frame :

```
Intro::DisplayIntro(d3ddev, introPath.c_str(), Surface, BackBuffer);
```

File : Intro.h

```
class Intro
{
public:
    static void Intro::DisplayIntro(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddevice, LPCSTR path, IDirect3DSurface9 *Surface, IDirect3DSurface9 *BackBuffer);
};
```

File : Intro.cpp

```
void Intro::DisplayIntro(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddevice, LPCSTR path, IDirect3DSurface9 *Surface, IDirect3DSurface9 *BackBuffer)
{
    D3DXIMAGE_INFO Info;

    D3DXGetImageInfoFromFile(path, &Info);
    d3ddevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(Info.Width, Info.Height, Info.Format, D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM, &Surface, NULL);

    D3DXLoadSurfaceFromFile(Surface, NULL, NULL, path, NULL, D3DX_FILTER_NONE, 0, NULL);

    d3ddevice->GetBackBuffer(0, 0, D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO, &BackBuffer);
    d3ddevice->UpdateSurface(Surface, NULL, BackBuffer, NULL);
}
```

then on StrikeOps_main.cpp , void : CloseD3D :

Surface->Release; and BackBuffer->Release; (yes they are declared as globals on StrikeOps_main.cpp

Comment: What "didn't work?" Did you get a compile-time error? A link error? A runtime error? Unexpected behavior? Note also that "debug my code" questions are generally considered off-topic here. With that in mind, please consider editing your question to be more specific about the problem you are having.